# Filter array containing strings having "ing"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

In Javascript, is there a way to select words containing something from an array. For example, `["swimming", "basketball", "chess", "rowing"]`, and I want to select only the items that contain "-ing" and apply a string to them.

> "I go" + "swimming", ect.

Inversely, is there a way to select items that DON'T contain that parameter. Words without "-ing"

> "I play" + "basketball", ect

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48889322/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it -

```js
var arr = ["swimming", "basketball", "chess", "rowing"];
arr.map(i=>i.indexOf("ing") != -1? console.log("I go "+ i):console.log("I play "+ i));

var res = arr.map(i=>(i.indexOf("ing") != -1?"I go " :"I play ")+ i); //if you want to put in array
console.log(res);
```

[Read here about Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you, I couldn't find the right method from googling. This should work great!

Comment: @atkinsta Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
let arr = ["swimming", "basketball", "chess", "rowing"];
let result = arr.map(s => (s.includes("ing")? "I go ": "I play ") + s);
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively you can filter this array using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and perform whatever action you want on each array.

```js
let arr = ["swimming", "basketball", "chess", "rowing"];

let strWithIng = arr.filter(s => s.includes("ing"));
let strWithoutIng = arr.filter(s => !s.includes("ing"));

console.log(strWithIng);
console.log(strWithoutIng);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Couldn't find a method by simply googling. Got muddy results.